# Positive area under the curve

Tags: integration

Is it true that if either $f(x) \ >\  0 $ or $ f(x) + f(x+1)\ >\ 0$, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ >\ 0$? I drew some graphs and the resulting area is always positive.

Comment: what have you tried so far / could you be more specific about your examples and graphs?

Comment: Also is the either / or a local property about one $ x $ (like $ f $ could satisfy the first property at one $ x_1 $ but satisfy the second property at another $ x_2 $ or are we comparing two different kinds of functions)?

Comment: I tried continuous functions and a few periodic graphs, trying to make the area negative. I have doubts about discontinuous functions. Like variations  of  Dirichlet functions which may satisfy the given conditions but are not integrable.

Comment: If function doesn't satisfy first condition at some point then it should satisfy second condition at the point where first condition failed. Only one function, which satisfies atleast one condition over all Real numbers

Comment: okay so the function can satisfy one property at one argument but the other property at another argument

Comment: Yes, atleast one of the condition should be true at all points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: \begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\\& =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^{1}f(x+n)\,dx\\& =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^{1}f(x+2n)+f(x+2n+1)\,dx\end{align}
Of course, to do these manipulations I assume the function to be (absolutely) integrable.

Comment: But are all functions which satisfy first two conditions mentioned integrable?

Comment: Of course not. Take the constant function for example.

Comment: I am sorry. Earlier I meant to say do all functions satisfying first two conditions have positive area.